# How can I use qemu-system-aarch64 to simulate a big,LITTLE platform?

Tags: qemu

I don't know how to use qemu-system-aarch64 to simulate a big.LITTLE platform?

I guess it can achieved by set the parameters "-machine " "-cpu", but I can't find a set of runnable parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (except if you want to write your own machine model) -- none of the machines that QEMU implements have big.LITTLE configurations.

In practice from QEMU's point of view there is no significant difference between how it would emulate the big and the little CPU types, so it doesn't make much difference to the guest anyway.